# Tubular neighbourhood style theorem reference request

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold and $Y$ be a closed submanifold. Then there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $Y$ in $X$ such that $Y$ is a deformation retract of $U$ right?

I can only find (stronger forms of) this in literature under the assumption that $Y$ is compact, which I don't think is necessary for the above statement. So what would be a reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you just want a reference request: see Theorem III.2.2, Corollary III.2.3, and the remark after Definition III.2.4 of Kosinski's *Differential Manifolds*.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I am a bit confused. Does Kosinski say that in my situation $U$ can even be choosen diffeomorphic to the normalbundle of $Y$ in $X$?

Comment: @Jan: I believe that is exactly what Kosinski says. (Sorry, I don't have the book with me right now, so am going by memory, but when I looked yesterday I think he defined the tubular neighborhood in terms of being diffeomorphic to normal bundle.)